# In what format does a WMS GetFeatureInfo return data?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wms, getfeatureinfo

In what format does a WMS GetFeatureInfo response return its data?

How can you get particular data from an HTML table using OpenLayers?

Answer (score 1):

Geoserver by default sends data back in html format. In the latest version of Geoserver, you can request the data in JSON as well. This will be the easiest way to get data in JavaScript and parse it according to your needs.

Please check the [Geoserver Docs](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#getfeatureinfo) for more details

Comment: If you call a WMS GetFeatureInfo, I think it'll return XML, not HTML

Comment: @BradHards try it out and let me know. Every geoserver i have installed and configured gives html output as default.

Answer (score 1):

The WMS specification mandates no formats at all. Most servers support text/plain and text/html, GeoServer adds a couple of GML variants, and JSON

Comment: Thats correct, and so you will have to write a parser for each WMS you query. You could try to persuade the data provider to set up a WFS, where the data structure is more well-defined (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Yes, WFS must support GML at the bare minimum.